# mongodb logrotation is being created but no logs written in that

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

i have installed the mongodb on my ubuntu server and also installed the logrotation in my server to rotate the log and create a new log with the data

/etc/mongod.conf

```
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  path: /var/mongodb/log/*.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
    authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:
```

/etc/logrotate.d/mongodb

```
 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log {
#    state /var/lib/logrotate/status-mongodb
    hourly
    rotate 96
    size 100M
    missingok
    create 0600 mongodb mongodb
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
         if /usr/sbin/pidof -s mongod > /dev/null ; then kill -USR1 $( /usr/sbin/pidof mongod ) ; fi
         /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
#        /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
#        /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /var/run/mongodb.pid)
#        systemctl restart mongod >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details

# global options do not affect preceding include directives

# rotate log files weekly
*/15

# use the adm group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root adm

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
#dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may also be configured here.
```

I have mentioned this all, but still there is no success of rotating the logs and logs are not getting written.

I tried changing the configuration forcefully started the logrotation, even tried to put the cron for it to create a log but still there is no success.

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/313677) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong, you must use

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```